# React + Redux + TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am trying to implement Redux to my React project. Right now, I got an error on my first page, and I can't solve it. My reducer, store, initial state are undifined when the component is initialized.

Am gonna try to put all important code, if something is missing, I can update the question.

Action type:

```
export default interface IAction<T>
{
    type: string;
    payload?: T;
    error?: boolean;
    meta?: any;
}
```

Root store:

```
import IBookingTypeState from '../pages/bookmark/home/IBookingTypeState';
import IBookingSearchState from '../pages/bookmark/search/bookingSearchState';

export default interface IStore
{
    readonly bookingSearchReducer: IBookingSearchState;
}
```

Root reducer:

```
import { combineReducers, Reducer, ReducersMapObject } from 'redux';

import IStore from './rootStore';
import BookingTypeReducer from './booking/bookingType/bookingTypeReducer';
import BookingSearchReducer from './booking/bookingSearch/bookingSearchReducer';

const reducerMap: ReducersMapObject =
{
    bookigSeacrhReducer: BookingSearchReducer.reducer
}

export default combineReducers(reducerMap) as Reducer<IStore>;
```

Action creator:

```
import IAction from '../../IAction';
import IBookingSearch from './../../../models/bookingSearch';

export default class BookingSearchAction
{
    public static readonly SET: string = 'BookingSearchAction.SET';
    public static readonly GET: string = 'BookingSearchAction.GET';

    public static setBookingsSearch(bookingSearch: IBookingSearch): IAction<IBookingSearch>
    {
        return {
            error: false,
            meta: null,
            payload: bookingSearch,
            type: BookingSearchAction.SET
        }
    }

    public static getBookingsSearch(): IAction<null>
    {
        return {
            error: false,
            meta: null,
            payload: null,
            type: BookingSearchAction.GET
        }
    }
}
```

**IBookingSearch** is just an interface to store the search data.

Reducer:

```
import IBookingSearch from './../../../models/bookingSearch';
import IBookingSearchState from './../../../pages/bookmark/search/bookingSearchState';
import IAction from './../../IAction';
import BookingSearchAction from './bookingSearchAction';

export default class BookingSearchReducer
{
    private static readonly _initialState: IBookingSearchState =
    ({
        searchParameters:
        {
            Arrival: new Date(),
            Departure: new Date(),
            Lenght: 0,
            Beam: 0,
            Draft: 0,
            ShorePower: 0,
            PromoCode: ''
        }
    });

    public static reducer(state: IBookingSearchState = BookingSearchReducer._initialState, action: IAction<IBookingSearch>) : IBookingSearchState
    {
        switch (action.type)
        {
            case BookingSearchAction.SET:
                return BookingSearchReducer._setBookingSearch(state, action);
            case BookingSearchAction.GET:
                return BookingSearchReducer._getBookingSearch(state, action);
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }

    private static _setBookingSearch(state: IBookingSearchState, action: IAction<IBookingSearch>) : IBookingSearchState
    {
        if (!action.payload)
        {
            return {
                ...state
            }
        }

        return {
            ...state,
            searchParameters: action.payload
        }
    }

    private static _getBookingSearch(state: IBookingSearchState, action: IAction<IBookingSearch>) : IBookingSearchState
    {
        return {
            ...state
        }
    }
}
```

Component where I wanna use it:

```
interface IStateToProps extends IBookingSearchState
{}

interface IDispatchToProps
{
    dispatch: (action: IAction<IBookingSearch>) => void;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: IStore): IStateToProps =>
({
    searchParameters: state.bookingSearchReducer.searchParameters
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<IAction<IBookingSearch>>): IDispatchToProps =>
({
    dispatch
});

class SearchFormDesktop extends React.Component<IStateToProps & IDispatchToProps & WithStyles<typeof styles> & RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}>
{
    private searchParameters: IBookingSearch = (null!);

    constructor(props: IStateToProps & IDispatchToProps & WithStyles<typeof styles> & RouteComponentProps<{}>)
    {
        super(props);
   }

    handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void =>
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.searchParameters
        {
            [e.target.name] = e.target.value
        }
    }

    handleSelectChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>): void =>
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.searchParameters
        {
            [e.target.name] = e.target.value
        }
    }

    private submitHandler = () =>
    {
        console.log(this.state);

        //dispatch state
        this.props.dispatch(BookingSearchAction.setBookingsSearch(this.searchParameters));

        this.props.history.push(Urls.bookingoffers);
    }

    render()
    {
        const css = this.props.classes;
        const enabled = this.searchParameters &&
                        this.searchParameters.Arrival &&
                        this.searchParameters.Departure &&
                        this.searchParameters.Beam &&
                        this.searchParameters.Lenght &&
                        this.searchParameters.Draft

        const Body = () =>
            <StackPanel stretch orientation="vertical" centerVertically className = { css.root }>
                <StackPanel  centerHorizontally centerVertically>
                    <h3>Short-Term Dockage</h3>
                </StackPanel>
                <DockPanel {...dockBottom}>
                    <StackPanel {...dockLeft}>
                        <DatePickerWithLapbel label="Arrival" name="arrival" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel  {...dockRight}>
                        <DatePickerWithLapbel label="Departure" name="departure" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel {...dockBottom}>
                    <StackPanel  {...dockLeft}>
                        <NumericInput label="Lenght" name="Lenght" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <NumericInput label="Beam" name="Beam" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel  {...dockRight}>
                        <NumericInput label="Draft" name="Draft" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel {...dockBottom}>
                    <SelectInput {...dockLeft} label="Shore Power (optional)" name="ShorePower" onChange={this.handleSelectChange}/>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel {...dockBottom}>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Typography variant="subtitle1" className={css.promo}>Add promo or group code</Typography>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel {...dockBottom}>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button variant="contained"
                                color="primary"
                                fullWidth={ true }
                                size="large"
                                className={css.button}
                                onClick = { this.submitHandler }
                                disabled={!enabled}
                                >
                            Check Availability
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DockPanel>
            </StackPanel>

        return Body();
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (withRoot(withStyles(styles)(SearchFormDesktop)));
```

And finaly the index.tsx

```
// create the saga middleware
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = createStore(Reducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)));
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

const container =
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer>
          <Router history={ history }>
            <IndexRoutes/>
          </Router>
        </AppContainer>
      </Provider>

const ROOT = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(container, ROOT);
```

In my project I am also using Material-UI.
Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps are injecting props into your component, meaning these props are not provided when the component is rendered in another component = when its constructor is magically called through JSX. And that's ok.

What's not ok is that you instructed TypeScript to blow up if the constructor doesn't receive these props:

```
constructor(props: IStateToProps & IDispatchToProps & WithStyles<typeof styles> & RouteComponentProps<{}>)
```

Therefore I'm recommending you to follow this pattern:

You'll need 2 interfaces. IProps which are props passed through jsx in the calling component. And IInjectedProps which extends IProps (and in your case, the rest of injected interfaces). In the constructor props are just IProps. That means you're asking typescript to blow up only if the called props are not respected.

```
interface IProps{
//strong typed properties expected from the component that renders this component
}

interface IInjectedProps extends IProps, IStateToProps, IDispatchToProps /*and anything else injected*/ {
//optionally add injected properties here
}

class SearchFormDesktop extends Component<IProps, IState> {
//...
get injected() {
   return this.props as IInjectedProps
}

//now you can use this.injected for injected props, and this.props for passed props. 
//Check their intellisense. Interface segregation ftw.

}
```

If you ever pick up one of these fancy newer functional components, instead of 'get injected' you can use:

```
injected = props as IInjectedProps
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a typo: `bookigSeacrhReducer`. You can add [redux-logger](https://github.com/LogRocket/redux-logger) middleware to see what the store actually contains.
2. `connect` will inject `this.props.searchParameters` and not `this.searchParameters`. You should read them from there.
3. I'm not familiar with Material UI, but you'd usually use [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). Which means that you'd store the current form state in either Redux store or component state, and modify it in your `handleChange` callback (by issuing an action, or `setState()` respectively.

There might be some other issues with your code, but it's hard to tell without the full context. Make sure it type-checks correctly.